# capacity of the vector changes after push_back()

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

Could someone explain why I do not get the same outputs?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Cell
{
    vector<int> vtx;
};

int main()
{
    vector <Cell> cells;
    Cell tmp;
    tmp.vtx.reserve(5);
    cells.push_back (tmp);
    cout << tmp.vtx.capacity() << endl;
    cout << cells[0].vtx.capacity() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you print before and after `push_back` to align with your titular question?

Answer (score 16):

Because taking a vector `A` and copying it to vector `B` does not guarantee that vector `B` will have the same capacity as vector `A`. Typically, the new vector will allocate only enough memory to hold the elements being copied into it.

In fact, there's an old trick that makes use of this, called the reduce-capacity trick:

```
int main()
{
   vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5 };
   v.clear();                   // capacity still non-zero

   vector<int>(v).swap(v);      // capacity now zero (maybe)
}
```

… though, technically, [whether this actually works is entirely implementation-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7829018/560648).

If you *move* the vector in, rather than copying it, then there are no re-allocations, the buffer is actually the same buffer, and the capacity does not change:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Cell
{
    vector<int> vtx;
};

int main()
{
    vector <Cell> cells;
    Cell tmp;
    tmp.vtx.reserve(5);
    cout << tmp.vtx.capacity() << endl;
    cells.push_back (std::move(tmp));
    cout << cells[0].vtx.capacity() << endl;
    return 0;
}

// 5
// 5
```

<sup>(Notice that I had to move the first `cout` call to before the move, otherwise I'd be `cout`ing something that is in an unknown state.)</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure `vector::capacity` has no preconditions, so checking the capacity of a moved from vector should be well defined. And in the first example, wouldn't you want to default construct the temporary `vector` instead of copy constructing it?

Comment: @Praetorian: It may be well defined but then you'd at least expect `0`, which is not what we're looking for. And no, you wouldn't, otherwise your `v` would end up entirely empty. Swapping the vector with itself is entirely deliberate (if ugly and silly).

Comment: @Praetorian: Oh, cos of the `clear`? Sure. I should have simply popped the last element, perhaps, for a better example.

Comment: `vector<T>(std::make_move_iterator(begin(v)), std::make_move_iterator(end(v))).swap(v);` for movable types I think is right.

Comment: @Yakk: I... don't know what to say

Comment: I was going to say "you really should not copy that vectors contents, but move it", wrote the code, noticed "hmm, that won't do much for `int` now will it, and the post uses `int`, how disappointing", and decided to splort a comment out anyhow.  In case you are wondering.

Comment: @Yakk: No probs ;) Thanks. _My_ comment, in case you are wondering, is about the marvels of C++, which is horrid

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I tend to write container/container-based converters myself: `vector<T>( range_move( v ) ).swap(v)` reads better.  It takes a pile of boilerplate however.  (`template<Range R> auto range_move(R&& r){ using std::begin; using std::end; return make_range(std::make_move_iterator(begin(r)), std::make_move_iterator(end(r))); }` and `template<Iterator I>struct range{ Iterator begin(); Iterator end(); ... template<Container C> operator C() { return {begin(), end()}; ... };`  etc etc -- I cannot *wait* for concepts to finally get here.)