# Will a call to std::vector::clear() set std::vector::capacity() to zero?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

If I use .reserve(items) on a vector, the vector will allocate enough memory for my guess of the number of items that I'll need.

If I later on use .clear(), will that just clear the vector or save my earlier defined reserve?

thanks.

Comment: That's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586634/

Comment: No it isn't, that question doesn't even _mention_ `clear()` . The only place where the word "clear" is used is in a comment that starts with "It's not clear to me if ..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the standard say about how calling clear on a vector changes the capacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467624/what-does-the-standard-say-about-how-calling-clear-on-a-vector-changes-the-capac)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is specified that `std::vector<T>::clear()` affects the size. It might not affect the capacity. For resetting the capacity, use the *swap trick*:

```
    std::vector<int> v1;

    // somehow increase capacity

    std::vector<int>().swap(v1);
```

***Note:*** Since this old answer is still getting upvotes (thus people read it), I feel the need to add that ***C++11*** has added `std::vector<...>::shrink_to_fit()`, which requests the vector to remove unused capacity.

Comment: It's so well-known you can even find it here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Clear-and-minimize not the similar "Shrink to fit" for reducing the capacity of the vector to the actual number of elements (when there are some).

Comment: It _may_ affect the capacity. It is _not_ required by the Standard to avoid changing the capacity or reallocating. So there's no guarantee either way.

Comment: @underscore_d: Thanks. I changed the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 13):

It will probably not release the reserved memory although I don't think the behaviour is specified in the standard.

**EDIT:** Ok, just checked and the standard only says that the post-condition is that `size() == 0` although I haven't come across a `vector` implementation that doesn't hold on to the reserved memory.

Comment: +1 for checking the standard and "probably" (I'd normally expect the memory to remain). On an embedded system I worked with I actually HAVE come across an implementation that releases the memory on a clear.

Answer (score 12):

No it won't. Try it out by calling `vector::capacity()`.

Further evidence of this is the appearance of `shrink_to_fit`. The standard's working draft mentions:

> Remarks:
>   shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request
>   to reduce capacity() to size(). [
>   Note: **The request is non-binding to
>   allow latitude for
>   implementation-specific optimizations**.
>   —end note ]

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't set reserve() to 0. Calling clear() calls the destructors of each element and removes them from the vector, leaving the container with size of 0, but the capacity remains unchanged.

Comment: _if your implementation leaves it unchanged._ the Standard does not require this, so capacity and allocation are allowed to change on `clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect the underlying buffer size. Which is why you have to use tricks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586634/shrinking-a-vector/586677#586677) to actually get rid of the buffer or make it smaller.