# Does clearing a vector affect its capacity?

Tags: c++, vector, size, std, capacity

I instantiate an `std::vector foo(1000)`.

`foo.size()` is now 1000 and `foo.capacity()` is also 1000.

If I clear the vector with `foo.clear()`, the `size()` is now 0, but what is the `capacity()`? Does the standard say anything about that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [will a call to std::vector.clear() also set the std::vector.reserve() to zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628345/will-a-call-to-stdvector-clear-also-set-the-stdvector-reserve-to-zero)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The capacity of a vector never decreases. That isn't mandated by the standard but it's so both in standard library implementations of VC++ and g++. In order to set the capacity just enough to fit the size, use the famous swap trick

```
vector<T>().swap(foo);
```

In C++11 standard, you can do it more explicitly:

```
foo.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: In 0x, `vector` has `shrink_to_fit`, but the standard remarks it's non-binding, which I presume means that implementation is not required to actually do that.

Comment: Can you please give a c++03 quote? It says that `erase(.begin(), .end())` invalidates all iterators and references after the point of erase. That doesn't seem to say anything about the capacity.

Comment: @Johannes: I said that it's not mentioned in the standard! I said on most implementations it's so!

Comment: U say that the capacity of a vector never decreases (even if no explicit call to "reserve" has happened). I cannot find the spec say so.

Comment: @Johannes: The spec ***doesn't*** say so. It just so happens to be implemented on VC++ and g++ implementations@

Comment: Ohh I see now. I was confused.

Comment: @sbi: Why? Please enlighten us :)

Comment: @Armen: Yes, you cannot pass rvalues *to* swap, but you can call swap *on* rvalues, hence my swapping of the arguments :)

Comment: @Fred, Armen: The vector will be shrunk, but not empty. I see now that this is what you also wrote in the accompanying text, but it's not what actually was asked. (I still think it would be a valuable additional hint (you can shrink a vector by _not_ clearing it!), but I think the original question should be answered first. (Oh, and I'd add a word about this being O(n).)

Comment: @Fred: If foo is empty, then this will make the capacity 0, no?

Comment: It will make the capacity as small as the implementation deems sensible.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "_U say that the capacity of a vector never decreases (even if no explicit call to "reserve" has happened). I cannot find the spec say so._" It does not work like that; which part of the spec allows the capacity to decrease?

Comment: @curiousguy i'm not familiar with that area of the spec anymore. but if nothing is said about the capacity value, its value is unspecified.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The spec says that after `reserve(n)` capacity is at least `n`. If nothing is said in the spec of `resize` about capacity it means that capacity is not allowed to change (unless there is a general statement that members of `vector` can shrink capacity). Unless the spec say that something can happen, it cannot happen.

Comment: @curious he did not call reserve

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What allows `vector` to decrease capacity here?

Comment: @curiousguy i don't know. as i said, i am not familiar with it anymore.

Answer (score 7):

To clear a vector and consume as little capacity as possible, use the swap trick:

```
std::vector<T>().swap(foo);
```

This creates an empty vector, swaps its internals with `foo`, and then destroys the temporary vector, getting rid of the elements that once belonged to `foo` and leaving `foo` as if it was freshly created.

Comment: I use `std::swap(foo, ItemContainer())` and have `typedef std::vector<T> ItemContainer` somewhere else when possible. It is more recognizable (IMHO) to have a temporary passed as an argument than having it be the calling object and an lvalue. Your way is 100% fine though.

Answer (score 1):

No, clear doesn't affect it's capacity(), it's remain the same even if you do clear. If you want to shrink the vector to fit, you can use the following trick after calling clear:
foo.swap(vector(foo));

Comment: It might. The standard does not specify it, so you should not rely on it. Though most implementations do it that way.

Comment: @BjörnPollex If the standard does not say that capacity can decrease, then it cannot.

Comment: @curiousguy: Actually if the standards don't explicitly say what happens, then it is open to happen any way the implementation wants to do it.

Comment: @ZanLynx No. The standard allows no such thing. **If the standard doesn't allow it, then it shall not happen.**

Comment: The standard mandates that the capacity does not change with a `clear` as `reserve` guarantees that further adding of elements do not relocate until the requested capacity is reached. This directly enforces `clear` to not reduce the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not say anything about the effect of `clear` on `capacity`.

Comment: The standard guarantees that after a `reserve` adding new elements can not result in relocation until size > capacity.This indirectly restricts what `clear`is allowed to do as it must still have the same capacity, otherwise using `push_pack` would invalidate iterators it is not allowed to invalidate.