# Why doesn't vector::clear remove elements from a vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector, undefined-behavior

When I use `clear()` on a `std::vector`, it is supposed to destroy all the elements in the `vector`, but instead it doesn't.

Sample code:

```
vector<double> temp1(4);
cout << temp1.size() << std::endl;
temp1.clear();
cout << temp1.size() << std::endl;

temp1[2] = 343.5; // I should get segmentation fault here ....

cout << "Printing..... " << temp1[2] << endl;
cout << temp1.size() << std::endl;
```

Now, I should have gotten segmentation fault while trying to access the cleared vector, but instead it fills in the value there (which according to me is very buggy)

Result looks as follows:

```
4
0
Printing..... 343.5
0
```

Is this normal?  This is a very hard bug to spot, which basically killed my code for months.

Comment: if you want to catch similar bugs, use a checked container (gcc can do this, or an external stl library, etc..)

Comment: A segmentation fault is produced by a memory management unit, a hardware component that C++ does not require. If failing to get a segfault caused your program to misbehave, then you have more serious issues.

Comment: you can use `at` operator which will do bounds checking and give an exception. I recommend using `at` instead of `[]`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: MSVC's libraries are checked in debug builds by default, and unchecked in release builds.  It's awesome.

Comment: You might consider trying to analyze your code with the clang static analyzer: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/. I think it would flag this mistake.

Comment: Other tools you may consider using - Purify, Valgrind etc - that will flag such memory access errors even if they may not result in a crash.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you access outside of the bounds of a vector, you get Undefined Behavior. That means anything can happen. Anything.

So you could get the old value, garbage, or a seg-fault. You can't depend on anything.

If you want bounds checking, use the `at()` member function instead of `operator []`. It will throw an exception instead of invoking Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 77):

You have no right to get a segmentation fault. For that matter, a segmentation fault isn't even part of C++. Your program *is* removing all elements from the vector, and you're illegally accessing the container out of bounds. This is undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen. And indeed, something happened.

Comment: Again the topic of C++ compilers, that format tour HDD on UB :D

Comment: From the C++ Standard to a 'class' full of newbie compilers - "YOU have the right to remain silent"... :-)

Answer (score 28):

From cppreference:

> ```
> void clear();
> ```
>
> Removes all elements from the container. Invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements. May invalidate any past-the-end iterators. **Many implementations will not release allocated memory after a call to `clear()`, effectively leaving the capacity of the vector unchanged.**

So the reason there is no apparent problem is because the vector still has the memory available in store. Of course this is merely implementation-specific, but not a bug. Besides, as the other answers point out, your program also does have Undefined Behavior for accessing the cleared contents in the first place, so technically anything can happen.

Comment: Is the highlighted part guaranteed by the standard, or is it rather just typical behavior?

Comment: But accessing out of bounds with `operator []` is still undefined behavior, so the the caller can't depend on getting the old value. Different compiler settings might, for example, write sentry values into the old elements.

Comment: @sasha.sochka Why does that matter?

Comment: All iterators, pointers and references related to this container are [invalidated.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/)

Comment: @MarkRansom The Standard just says it will clear the container of all its elements. I can't find anything (so far) which guarantees this behavior.

Comment: @0x499602D2, I only ask because cppreference.com is a wiki and it can contain inaccurate information.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Sequence container requirements (§23.2.3/Table 100) states *a.clear() - Destroys all elements in a. Invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator.* cppreference is wrong about both the `capacity()` being unchanged, and past-the-end iterators remaining valid.

Comment: @Praetorian I read that and I was confused by how cppreference would say the exact opposite. I will delete my answer if it needed.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is misleading. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882799/does-clearing-a-vector-affect-its-capacity -- I've updated cppreference to reflect that this is implementation-specific.

Comment: @NateKohl Why does the edit still say "Any past-the-end iterators are not invalidated.", the Standard says that they *may* be invalidated.

Answer (score 8):

Let's imagine you're rich (perhaps you are or you aren't ... whatsoever)!

Since you're rich you buy a piece of land on Moorea (Windward Islands, French Polynesia). 
You're very certain it is a nice property so you build a villa on that island and you live there.
Your villa has a pool, a tennis court, a big garage and even more nice stuff.

After some time you leave Moorea since you think it's getting really boring. A lot of sports but few people.
You sell your land and villa and decide to move somewhere else.

If you come back some time later you may encounter a lot of different things but you cannot be certain about even one of them.

- Your villa may be gone, replaced by a club hotel.
- Your villa may be still there.
- The island may be sunken.
- ...

Who knows?
Eventhough the villa may not longer belong to you, you might even be able to jump in the pool or play tennis again.
There may also be another villa next to it where you can swim in an even bigger pool with nobody distracting you.

You have no guarantee of what you're gong to discover if you come back again and that's the same with your vector which contains three pointers in the implementations I've looked at:
(The names may be different but the function is mostly the same.)

- `begin` points to the start of the allocated memory location (i.e. X)
- `end` which points to the end of the allocated memory +1 (i.e. begin+4)
- `last` which points to the last element in the container +1 (i.e. begin+4)

By calling clear the container may well destroy all elements and reset `last = begin;`. The function `size()` will most likely `return last-begin;` and so you'll observe a container size of 0.
Nevertheless, `begin` may still be valid and there may still be memory allocated (`end` may still be `begin+4`). You can even still observe values you set before clear().

```
std::vector<int> a(4);
a[2] = 12;
cout << "a cap " << a.capacity() << ", ptr is " << a.data() << ", val 2 is " << a[2] << endl;
a.clear();
cout << "a cap " << a.capacity() << ", ptr is " << a.data() << ", val 2 is " << a[2] << endl;
```

Prints:

> a cap 4, ptr is 00746570, val 2 is 12
>   a cap 4, ptr is 00746570, val 2 is 12

Why don't you observe any errors? It is because `std::vector<T>::operator[]` does not perform any out-of-boundary checks (in contrast to `std::vector<T>::at()` which does).
Since C++ doesn't contain "segfaults" your program seems to operate properly.

*Note: On MSVC 2012 `operator[]` performs boundary checks if compiled in the debug mode.*

Welcome to the land of undefined behaviour! Things may or may not happen. You probably can't even be cartain about a single circumstance.
You can take a risk and be bold enough to take a look into it but that is probably not the way to produce reliable code.

Answer (score 6):

The `operator[]` is efficient but comes at a price: it does not perform boundary checking.

There are safer yet efficient way to access a vector, like iterators and so on.

If you need a vector for random access (i.e. not always sequential), either be very careful on how you write your programs, or use the less efficient `at()`, which in the same conditions would have thrown an exception.

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say that many implementations don't deallocate after a clear -- see the comments on 0x499602D2's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can get seg fault but this is not for sure since accessing out of range elements of vector with `operator[]` after `clear()` called before is just undefined behavior. From your post it looks like you want to try if elements are destroyed so you can use `at` public function for this purpose:

> The function automatically checks whether n is within the bounds of
>   valid elements in the vector, throwing an out_of_range exception if it
>   is not (i.e., if n is greater or equal than its size). This is in
>   contrast with member operator[], that does not check against bounds.

in addition, after `clear()`:

> All iterators, pointers and references related to this container are
>   invalidated.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
temp1.at(2) = 343.5;
```

instead of

```
temp1[2] = 343.5;
```

you would find the problem. It is recommended to use the function of `at()`, and the `operator[]` doesn't check the boundary. You can avoid the bug without knowing the implementation of STL vector.

BTW, i run your code in my **Ubuntu (12.04)**, it turns out like what you say. However, in **Win7**, it's reported "Assertion Failed".

Well, that reminds me of the type of stringstream. If define the sentence

```
stringstream str;
str << "3456";
```

If REUSE `str`, I was told to do like this

```
str.str("");
str.clear();
```

instead of just using the sentence

```
str.clear();
```

And I tried the `resize(0)` in **Ubuntu**, it turns out useless.

Comment: I'm curious - is there a way to make GCC work like MSVC and detect such issues automatically? I usually program on Windows and I find it **very** helpful, but I also work under Linux and I'd like to use the same error checking mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

try to access to an elements  sup than **4** that you use for constructor may be you will get your segmentation fault 
An other idea from cplusplus.com:

*Clear content*

Removes all elements from the vector (which are destroyed), leaving the container with a size of 0.

A reallocation is not guaranteed to happen, and the vector capacity is not guaranteed to change due to calling this function. A typical alternative that forces a reallocation is to use swap:

**vector().swap(x);   // clear x reallocating**

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal. `clear()` doesn't guarantee a reallocation. Try using `resize()` after `clear()`.

Comment: `resize` doesn't guarantee a reallocation either, but it does guarantee that the elements will be reset to known values.

Answer (score 0):

One important addition to the answers so far: If the class the vector is instanciated with provides a destructor, it will be called on clearing (and on `resize(0)`, too).

Try this:

```cpp
struct C
{
    char* data;
    C()           { data = strdup("hello"); }
    C(C const& c) { data = strdup(c.data); }
    ~C()          { delete data; data = 0; };
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<C> v;
    v.push_back(C());
    puts(v[0].data);
    v.clear();
    char* data = v[0].data; // likely to survive
    puts(data);             // likely to crash
    return 0;
}
```

This program most likely will crash with a segmentation fault - but (very likely) not at `char* data = v[0].data;`, but at the line `puts(data);` (use a debugger to see).

Typical vector implementations leave the memory allocated intact and leave it as is just after calling the destructors (however, no guarantee - remember, it is undefined behaviour!). Last thing that was done was setting data of the C instance to nullptr, and although not valid in sence of C++/vector, the memory is still there, so can access it (illegally) without segmentation fault. This will occur when dereferencing `char* data` pointer in puts, as being null...