# Calling clear() on a vector does not actually delete data in data()?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, erase, shrink

**Summary**:

It seems like just calling `clear()` on a vector is not enough to clear it.

```cpp
vector_full_of_stuff.clear();
```

I had to call `clear()` and then `shrink_to_fit()` to completely delete all data inside of it.

```cpp
vector_full_of_stuff.clear();
// AND THEN  
vector_full_of_stuff.shrink_to_fit();
```

What gives? This became a problem because when I would call `data()` on a vector, it would include stuff that I thought should have been cleared when I called `clear()` earlier in the code.

**Additional Details**:

I am doing an computer networking assignment where I have to parse a PASV command result into an IP and Port Number. While parsing a fictitious PASV command result separated by commas, I noticed that if I parse a three digit followed by a two digit I get that third digit from the previous parse when calling `data()` even though I shouldn't (?) because I called `clear()` before it.

> ex.
>   PASV Command Result = 209,202,252,54,19,15
>   The "2" from "252" carries over into "19" when parsing.

**Code**:

```cpp
// this one actually deletes data
void splitString(string str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    vector<char> word_buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == delimiter) {
            out->push_back(word_buffer.data());
            word_buffer.clear();
            word_buffer.shrink_to_fit();
        } else {
            word_buffer.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    out->push_back(word_buffer.data());
    word_buffer.clear();
}
// 

// this one doesn't
// the only thing that's different about this one 
// is that its missing shrink_to_fit()
void splitString(string str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    vector<char> word_buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == delimiter) {
            out->push_back(word_buffer.data());
            word_buffer.clear();
            // word_buffer.shrink_to_fit(); // need this to delete data
        } else {
            word_buffer.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    out->push_back(word_buffer.data());
    word_buffer.clear();
}
//

// main driver code
int main() {
    vector<string> user_input_tokens;
    string port = "209,202,252,54,19,15";
    splitString(port, ',', &user_input_tokens);
    for (string str : user_input_tokens) {
        cout << str << ".";
    }
}
//
```

Expected Output:

```
209.202.252.54.19.15.
```

Actual Output:

```
209.202.252.542.192.152.
```

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't vector::clear remove elements from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286271/why-doesnt-vectorclear-remove-elements-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector's `data()` method returns a raw pointer to the vector's allocated array in memory.  `clear()` destroys the *contents* of that array if needed and sets the vector's `size()` to 0, but does not reallocate the array itself, and thus does not change the vector's `capacity()`.  Calling the vector's `shrink_to_fit()` method reallocates the array so its `capacity()` matches its `size()`, if possible (`shrink_to_fit()` is advisory only and not *guaranteed* to actually do anything).

Also, when constructing a `std::string` from a `char*` pointer by itself, the char data needs to be null-terminated, but your data is not. You need to push a null terminator into the vector before using `data()`:

```cpp
void splitString(const string &str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    vector<char> word_buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == delimiter) {
            word_buffer.push_back('\0');
            out->push_back(word_buffer.data());
            word_buffer.clear();
        } else {
            word_buffer.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!word_buffer.empty()) {
        word_buffer.push_back('\0')
        out->push_back(word_buffer.data());
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can simply take the vector's `size()` into account when constructing the strings, no null terminators needed:

```cpp
void splitString(const string &str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    vector<char> word_buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == delimiter) {
            out->push_back(string(word_buffer.data(), word_buffer.size()));
            // alternatively:
            // out->emplace_back(word_buffer.data(), word_buffer.size());
            word_buffer.clear();
        }
        else {
            word_buffer.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!word_buffer.empty()) {
        out->push_back(string(word_buffer.data(), word_buffer.size()));
        // alternatively:
        // out->emplace_back(word_buffer.data(), word_buffer.size());
    }
}
```

That being said, there are other ways to implement a `splitString()` function without needing the `word_buffer` vector at all, eg:

```cpp
void splitString(const string &str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    string::size_type start = 0, pos = str.find(delimiter);
    while (pos != string::npos) {
        out->push_back(str.substr(start, pos-start));
        start = pos + 1;
        pos = str.find(delimiter, start);
    }
    if (start < str.size()) {
        if (start > 0) {
            out->push_back(str.substr(start));
        } else {
            out->push_back(str);
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/BxaSNn)

```cpp
void splitString(const string &str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    istringstream iss(str);
    string word;
    while (getline(iss, word, delimiter))
        out->push_back(std::move(word));
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/JqP4FE)

But, even if you wanted to buffer the words manually, a `std::string` would have made more sense than a `std::vector<char>`, especially since you are outputting `std::string` values:

```cpp
void splitString(const string &str, char delimiter, vector<string> * out) {
    string word_buffer;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == delimiter) {
            out->push_back(std::move(word_buffer));
            word_buffer.clear();
        } else {
            word_buffer.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!word_buffer.empty()) {
        out->push_back(std::move(word_buffer));
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rkkMmw)

Comment: I would make it clearer that the main issue is that `string(const char*)` expects a null-terminated string, but `data()` is not null-terminated. In the last version, could do `out->push_back(std::move(word_buffer));`.