# Does vector::erase reduce vector::capacity?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer

Cppreference only says:

> Removes specified elements from the container. 1) Removes the element
>   at pos. 2) Removes the elements in the range [first; last).
>
> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the
>   erase, including the end() iterator.
>
> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end()
>   iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as
>   a value for pos.
>
> The iterator first does not need to be dereferenceable if first==last:
>   erasing an empty range is a no-op.

Comment: Looks like it does get resized: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: @IanA.B.King Of course the *size* have to be changed since an element is removed, but the *capacity* doesn't have to change.

Comment: comparable [Does clearing a vector affect its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6882799/6717178) It mentions: the standard does not specify this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily no. When reading the C++ standard (and cppreference proxies the standard remarkably well), if something is not explicitly mentioned, then assume such a something is not required.

It would possibly be sub-optimal for a C++ Standard Library implementation to do so.

Comment: >  When reading the C++ standard (and cppreference proxies the standard remarkably well), if something is not explicitly mentioned, then assume such a something is not required.
So I guess the answer is it's not necessary?

Comment: In short the answer is indeed "not necessarily".

Answer (score 6):

No. That's implied by the fact that iterators, pointers and references prior to the point of erase remain valid. Reducing the capacity would require a reallocation.

Comment: And complexity requirement implies too.

Answer (score 4):

With other constraints as complexity or iterator validity, that might force implementation in some way.

Here:

> Complexity:
>   Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions) plus the number of elements after the last element deleted (moving).

So decreasing capacity and moving old objects is a resized buffer is not possible. Except in the case when `first` and `begin` are the same.

Decreasing just the capacity number would be possible, but I don't see any sane implementation doing that.

Comment: "other constraints ... iterator invalidity" - the iterator being invalidated isn't a constraint.  By the standard saying it's invalidated, the emphasis is that there is no requirement on the implementation to do anything to keep it valid.  The implementation doesn't NEED to go out of it's way to invalidate it, because it's UB to use it - which might be .... that it works.

Comment: @UKMonkey: I meant "which iterator should stay valid", so that if `f()` should not invalidate iterators, then reallocation could not happen. it invalidate some implementation as COW for string for example.

Comment: Ahh - that makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 3):

The only vector operations that affect the capacity are the ones that invalidate **all** iterators, pointers and references, because they have reallocated the storage and moved the elements.

There is nothing in the `Allocator` concept that would allow it to change the allocation size in place, so the capacity can't change in that manner either.

In theory an implementation could specialise on `std::allocator` and reallocate, under the "As-if" rule, but I doubt there are any serious implementations that would do such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

A quick example could have cleared your doubt :( compiled using VS2017 )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intVec{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::cout << "Capacity and size before erase : " << intVec.capacity() << ", "<< intVec.size() << std::endl;
    intVec.erase(intVec.begin() + 3);
    std::cout << "Capacity and size after erase : " << intVec.capacity() << ", " << intVec.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> **Output :**
>
> Capacity and size before erase : 10, 10
>
> Capacity and size after erase : 10, 9

Note that while `capacity()` doesn't decrease after the erase, the `size()` certainly does.

Comment: It's worth detailing your toolchain when producing a counter-example.

Comment: This doesn't show the standard *requires* no change in capacity, merely that it *allows* no change

Comment: @Caleth :My intention was to show with an example that erase does not trigger a reallocation, thereby leading to no change in capacity.

Comment: a single example cannot serve as proof of a general concept

Comment: ..i mean your example is fine, but you cannot draw any conclusion from it for the general case

Comment: @user463035818 : I do agree with you on that.

Comment: @Caleth, and not even that, the compiler might be non-conformant :)