# Effective way of storing STL object of one type into another type

Tags: c++

I have an STL object for e.g.

```
std::vector <long> vec1;
```

and I want to convert this to a vector

```
std::vector <int> vec2;
```

using

```
std::map<long,int>map;
```

Is there a efficient way of doing it where the elements of vec1 that are mapped to vec2 get deleted dynamically so as to reduce vec1's size? This algorithm should consume least amount of memory and should be fast. Is it possible to do this in-place? Would std::remove_if do a good job? How is the performance compared to chunked processing i.e., vec1 is broken into chunks; each chunk is then mapped and stored in vec2; chunk is deleted from memory after this.

vec1 (and vec2) could also be a vector (vector of vector).

Comment: why not `std::map<vector<long>, vector<int>> longToIntMap`

Comment: I do not want to store vec1 in memory after I get vec2

Comment: Why would you want to go through the step of using a `map`? Why not simply loop over the first vector, and push the value into the second vector?

Comment: unless you want both vector1 and vector2?

Comment: If you want to "reclaim" the memory used by the first vector, then you could simply `clear` it after doing the copy.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Good question. I do not know beforehand how the elements are mapped. So a map is required!!

Comment: Ah, you already _have_ a `map` and want to use that in your copying?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah. Also, vec1 could be a vector of vectors. So a map is needed

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and `clear()` will not release the memory; it just resets the *size*. The *capacity* is maintained (the memory *behind* the vector). A [clear+swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628345/will-a-call-to-stdvector-clear-also-set-the-stdvector-reserve-to-zero) is what you want for a full-clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a efficient way of doing it where the elements of vec1 that are mapped to vec2 get deleted dynamically so as to reduce vec1's size?

Removing things from the beginning of a `vector` is inefficient, because it causes the remaining elements to shift forward to fill the empty space at the beginning. And the memory freed at the end of the vector isn't returned to the heap anyway, because it's all part of one big memory block, released all at once.

The better fit here would be `std::queue` which uses the `std::deque` data structure by default. This comprises a sequence of small memory blocks. You can free the memory at the beginning using `pop`.

```
#include <queue>

std::queue <long> vec1;
std::queue <int> vec2;

while ( ! vec1.empty() ) {
    vec2.push( value_map[ vec1.front() ] );
    vec1.pop();
}
```

You could also use `std::deque` objects directly. Then you would use `push_front` and `pop_back`. It's a pretty cool class; it maintains the illusion of a "flat" sequence of objects even when they aren't in a monolithic, flat array like `vector` uses.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. So even when elements are popped from a vector it's length doesn't change (wouldn't this memory be freed)?

Comment: @SumanVajjala A `vector` has a `size()` (the number of valid objects contained) and a `capacity()` (the amount of heap space used). `pop_back`, `erase`, etc do not affect `capacity`.

Comment: So a vector reserves some memory (storage size given by capacity()) even if it's size() = 0?

Comment: @SumanVajjala No, the `capacity` increases geometrically as `size` grows. (For N `push_back` operations, expect O(log N) reallocations to a larger `capacity`.) But when `size` shrinks, `capacity` remains at the high-water mark.

Comment: Ok. Kewl. Thanks again for your suggestions/comments!! Does it matter if capacity remains highest? Vec1 will not be used anywhere after the conversion.

Comment: If the old vector will be disappearing out of scope anyway, it will self clean on destruction. If it is a persistent vector and you're that worried about space consider a [clear-and-swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628345/will-a-call-to-stdvector-clear-also-set-the-stdvector-reserve-to-zero) operation to swap it with a genuinely empty vector.

Comment: @WhozCraig,Potatoswatter Thanks once again. I learned a great deal today :)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a map, you could try this (C++11) solution:

```
std::vector<long> vec1;  // Original vector
std::map<long, int> map; // How to map the `long` value to an `int`

std::vector<int> vec2;  // The destination vector

for (const auto l : vec1)
    vec2.push_back(map[l]);
```

If the first vector is a vector-of-vectors, simply use nested loops:

```
for (const auto& v : vec1)
{
    for (const auto l : v)
        vec2.push_back(map[l]);
}
```

Comment: Would this automatically delete element of vec1 after pushing it into vec2?

Comment: I do not want to store all the elements of vec1 in the memory during processing. Adds to memory consumption. Is there a efficient way where after adding element/some elements to vec2, they can be deleted from vec1 (remove & resize)

Comment: @SumanVajjala See the SO question linked to in the comment by WhozCraig.

Comment: @SumanVajjala If you're on a platform where memory is so limited that you can't have two vectors in memory at the same time, then I suggest you should rethink your algorithms. Unless the vector contains several millions of elements, even a 15 year old PC should be able to handle it without too many problems.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and comments Joachim. While this seems simple enough, the situation can be exacerbated in case where I have about 1 million longs/core and added to this storage about 10 million doubles/core. So, I was looking for algos which minimize memory storage overheads!!

Comment: I'm marginally hoping you understand that on many/most/but-not-all platforms `long` and `int` are, in fact, the same size. If, however, you were absolutely married to the idea of taking an enormous buffer of `int` type 'A' and converting to a larger `int` type 'B' *and* type 'B' is an aligned size multiple of type 'A'* (ex: `int32_t` and `int64_t` (2x), or `int16_t` and `int64_t` (4x)) this is possible via raw memory and some back-to-front scanning. At least then your would never exceed more memory than the final requirement, but you would have to manage it yourself.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do not know that long and int are of the same size!! Many thanks for pointing out. Wouldn't dynamic allocation/deletion affect the speed of the algo? How do I manage this?

Comment: @SumanVajjala they're not guaranteed to be, but on most systems they are. A quick sizeof() comparison of each will tell you if they are.

Comment: @SumanVajjala just realized I didn't answer your second question. I can answer it with another question, in fact. You said: "Wouldn't dynamic allocation/deletion affect the speed of the algo?" Question: What exactly do you think a `std::vector<>` gets its memory *from* ??

Comment: @SumanVajjala Exactly. The same place you would get it from if you were managing it yourself (though I wouldn't without a smart pointer). Anyway, I'd check to see if you get any win by sizing from long-to-int at all i.e. `if (sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)) { this is pointless }`. And if there *is* a downsize, there are ways to roll the values in place, but they have to *start* with a dynamic buffer of long, and the algorithm would use `realloc()` rather than `new`. Think about it for awhile. If I get time I'll try and throw together a sample.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks a zillion :) I would also try to figure out although I am no expert in CS :(

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements from the source vector as you copy them to the destination vector.

```
while (!source.empty()) {
  destination.push_back(map[source.back()]);
  source.pop_back();
}
```

This requires O(*n* log *m*) time and O(1) space, where *n* is `source.size()` and *m* is `map.size()`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) I was wondering if there is a in-place hack or something for this problem