# Does clear() affect the bucket count of std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

There are plenty of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628345/will-a-call-to-stdvector-clear-also-set-the-stdvector-reserve-to-zero) with `std::vector`, but what about `std::unordered_set`?

My real question (closely related) is this; is it efficient to reuse the same unordered set by clearing it before each use, if I reserve what I know to be a reasonable size beforehand?

Comment: I'd say this would be implementation specific. The standard only specifies that `clear()` erases all elements in the container.

Comment: I think the [same argument applies as for `std::vector::reserve`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18467916): `bucket_count` is part of the observable state; it is allowed to be changed on insertion, but it's not explicitly allowed to change on `rehash` or `reserve` (or even on `erase` as far as I can see..).

Comment: @dyp: you've lost me... "`bucket_count`... not explicitly allowed to change on `rehash` or `reserve`" - the latter exist to allow the number of bucket (thus `bucket_count()`) to be modified - the former directly accepts a new number of buckets (but is subject to a `size() / max_load_factor()` sanity check) and the latter derives it from a number of anticipated elements and the current `max_load_factor`.  "explicit" or not that's what they do.

Comment: @TonyD Hmm seems I was confused. Of course it is explicitly allowed to change on insertion, `rehash` and `reserve`, but not `clear` nor `erase`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formal answer is: it depends on implementation.

Informal answer is: `unordered_set` inside has an array (of some kind) of buckets, and most likely the implementation is consistent with `vector`, so this array won't be deleted when `clear()` is called. So calling `clear()` most likely will give some benefit.

Comment: Thanks, as with Jonathan Potter's answer; it's good to know that it's not specified. Using `reserve` before each use is already a gain in performance anyway.