# std::vector and boost::container::vector both of them do not release GPU memory

Tags: c++, vector, boost, memory-leaks, stdvector

I have a `std::vector` of structure and a `cv::Mat` in each structure. I do `vec.erase(iter)` to remove specific element from vector. But std::vector does not release memory indeed. As I check GPU memory it reaches to `8GB` while `vec` has a few element.

Also I utilized `boost::container::vector` to creating `vec` but also memory did not release. How could I release memory while vector really has a few members.

I'm worrying about memory leaks.

I also did `vec.shrink_to_fit()` but it was not useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shrinking a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586634/shrinking-a-vector)

Comment: @AhmedAEK shrink_to_fit does not help.

Answer (score 0):

`vector.erase()` only invalidates iterators and references *from the erased element onward* (as following elements are moved forward).

*Shrinking* the vector (a contiguous memory container) would require allocating a new, smaller memory block, and copying over *all* vector contents. This would invalidate *all* iterators and references.

Your memory is not leaked. The vector just retains the memory (capacity > size).

`shrink_to_fit()` is non-binding. It is a *request* for the implementation to release unused memory at the end of the vector. The implementation may legally ignore that request.

You could do the "copy over to a new vector of appropriate size" manually.

Or, depending on your use case, using a `forward_list`, `list`, or `deque` might be a better, more memory-efficient fit.

Comment: Does linked list or `forward_list` has a better performance than `std::vector`? Does C++ retains memory in this case, also?

Comment: @BarzanHayati "Better performance" is relative. They use one (`forward_list`) resp. two (`list`) additional pointers per element. Neither allows random access. `forward_list` can only be iterated forward, `list` also backward. But erasing an element is O(1), and the memory for the element can immediately be released. It's a trade-off, as everything.

Comment: Random access granted by language not by OS, am I right? If language does that why C++ does not release memory as an extra option?

Comment: @BarzanHayati Random access has nothing to do with the OS. "Extra options" can make a class unwieldly, and `vector` is supposed to be the workhorse of C++. Your use-case -- frequent `erase()`, itself a rather expensive operation -- is uncommon. Perhaps have a look at Boost.Container's [stable_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.stable_vector).

Comment: Thanks: Yes I do a lot of `erase()` and `push_back()`.

Comment: But -- if I may ask -- why are you doing this in one massive vector? I can't help but think that your problem is not so much "which container to use", but "why is all this *in one container* in the first place?"

Comment: A vector of structure to hold enough information of tracked faces. So I must add a new persons and remove disappeared ones**(Too many adds and removes)**. As **std::vector** does not release memory(here **GPU memory**), I'm looking for a suitable alternative container. I'm not sure which one is better: `std::vector` , `std::forward_list`, `boost::container::stable_vector` or `boost::container::vector`. This alternative should be fast enough, because I do a lot of searches by `std::find_if` or `boost::container::find_if`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248156/discussion-between-devsolar-and-barzanhayati).